# Calculating risk from multinomial logistic regression and competing risks

Tags: multinomial-logit, competing-risks

I’m interested in predicting certain events an entity can experience. With logistic regression I would estimate the risk of a single event using p= exp(ß0 + ß1*x1 + ... + ßk*xk)/(1+exp(ß0 + ß1*x1 + ... + ßk*xk)).

Can I still use this formula if I obtain the coefficients using multinomial logistic regression?

And if I include all possible events an entity can have, does that automatically take care of competing risks?

Comment: Need to specify exactly what kind of model you used.

Comment: Multinomial logistic regression.